# Online calendar with JSON/jCal support

Tags: calendar, cloud

I need an online calendar that can display dated events from a JSON feed.  In other words, I'd like to be able to provide an URL and have it periodically import all the dated events found, and display them on the calendar to a user.

Ideally, Google Calendar would just let me specify a URL that returns JSON events, but I don't see a way to do that.  I do see that I could use the Google Calendar Java API to do the conversion myself, but was interested to see if there was another way.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can do it using html5 on chrome.

`<form>
  Birthday:
  <input type="date" name="bday">
</form>`

references: http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date